# Different view key and spend key after importing private key?

Tags: viewkey, spend-key

I created a wallet and got a spend key and view key. Then i imported that wallet into [Monerujo](https://monerujo.io) and there i got a different view key and a different spend key.

I guess that's correct? It's kind of disturbing that there is not only one view / spend key.

Comment: How did you import the private key?  It is a highly error prone process to enter 64 hexadecimal characters for the *spend key*, unless you use restore from the 25 Electrum words.

Comment: I entered the 25 words

Answer (score 1):

For deterministic wallets, you might want to use [**addresstests**](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html) JavaScript-based code to examine a low valued Monero wallet.

Also examine results of the [**XMR**](https://github.com/skaht/XMR) C++ package script commands:

**% echo "wipeout unnoticed origin timber corrode diet vats fences budget rotate iguana hive koala tuition shackles ticket fossil edited long beer shuffled lukewarm cogs atom hive" | ./inverse_mnemonics | ./xmr**

```
Seed                 : b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9
Private Spend Key    : c3b6b5a322e23c37ec9ac7edadd379d6c384efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcd09
Private View Key     : c8bc08b2d1ddb3056c43326f3576f7b20e3f626bb00a8ef3b4975dceeab85301
Public Spend Key     : d4ccd3a5f5af9ae368ef20ddc33a7c6422945dc2d1cb61c10c201752ece97bcd
Public View Key      : 90311e7f42443ad0579229154164fbaf882e0b9b0ae3caa728fb9ba6010899e2
Monero Address       : 49gq7ur2BzHf3ALDLNBJ4jHkSGcUT92AtZHoUS6ykkBLbPDpWV2VJrDbrBPV5G5kpzWMt2iXUwYNDUxfQqe4McMvSc79f9W
Electrum Seed Words  : swiftly potato fugitive upstairs jailed people plywood moon koala reunion repent muffin knuckle tugs sewage ticket fossil edited long beer shuffled both gills hexagon beer
```

**% ./sc_reduce32 b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9**

```
c3b6b5a322e23c37ec9ac7edadd379d6c384efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcd09
```

**% echo b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9 | ./bytes_to_words**

```
wipeout unnoticed origin timber corrode diet vats fences budget rotate iguana hive koala tuition shackles ticket fossil edited long beer shuffled lukewarm cogs atom hive
```

**% echo c3b6b5a322e23c37ec9ac7edadd379d6c384efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcd09 | ./bytes_to_words**

```
swiftly potato fugitive upstairs jailed people plywood moon koala reunion repent muffin knuckle tugs sewage ticket fossil edited long beer shuffled both gills hexagon beer
```

Notice with **sc_reduce32** normalization how two different seeds (represented as hexadecimal numbers or Electrum seed words) will result in the same set of spend keys, view keys, and the same address.